# problem with garch in Rstudio

Tags: r

I want to test the day of the week effect on stock returns. I used the following regression $Y_t=a_1D_1+a_2D_2+a_3D_3+a_4D_4+a_5D_5$ . Where $Y_t$ is stock return at time $t$, $D_i$ is a dummy variable for each day of the week monday to friday.

I have noticed that data suffers from volatility clustering, so I decided to add garch(1,1) model on top of that regression.

I tried the following code in Rstudio

```
mainmodel<-lm(Return~monday+tuesday+wednesday+thursday+friday-1)

garchspec<-ugarchspec(variance.model = list(garchorder= c(1,1)), mean.model = mainmodel)
```

Eventually it tells me

Warning messages:

```
1: unidentified option(s) in mean.model:
 coefficients residuals effects rank fitted.values assign qr df.residual xlevels call terms model 


2: unidentified option(s) in variance.model:
 garchorder
```

What am I doing wrong? Could you please explain me how to fit garch (1,1) on top of the regression model I am using?

Comment: This question is off-topic for this board. You should look at the documentation for `rugarch::ugarchspec`, as you have not specified either argument correctly at all (for the variance it should be `garchOrder`, and you need to supply regressors for the mean with `external.regressors` in the `mean.model` list, not just put an already fitted `lm` object in there).

Comment: I would add to @ChrisHaug comment, "try this question on stack overflow because it seems more related to programming"

Comment: @ChrisHaug,  thanks very much!

Comment: I think this should have been migrated to the Quantitative Finance forum.